# How do I find a complete list of extensions installed in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I want that list, because if something horrible happens, and I'll have to reinstall Visual Studio - I'll need this list, so that I can recreate the same development environment. This also makes it hard to search for updates - I can not see the versions of currently installed plug-ins.

So, is there a single place in Visual Studio, that would show me a complete list of plug-ins and their versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio->Installed Products

Comment: Oooh. I new it displays the list, but I didn't see, that you can select any of the products and see a more detailed info about it (some plug-ins don't have a version number in their title, but they do have it in the detailed info). Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Help->About Visual Studio you typically see a list of extensions.

Comment: I hope you won't mind, that I will accept the other answer. It's just that - Evgeny has needs reputation increase more than you do.
I'll give you an up-vote, though.